# React: Enzyme's it local scope does not work

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using React. I used basic redux counter by using redux-toolkit. I am really new in testing. I am using Enzyme and Jest for the test. My redux counter intialState is 1. From my testing, inside `it` scope I first take the intialState then after simulate('click') increase button, I got result 2, which I expected. When I try to test my decrease button inside the `it` scope it takes the result from increase's `it` scope. If I put intialState 1 inside the decrease button's `it` scope, it gives me failed test because it expected 2.

**This is my testing file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from "enzyme"; // mount is fulldom renderning function with children
import Counter from 'components/counter';
import Root from "root/index"; // this is the root index which connect react component and redux

let wrapped;
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapped = mount(
    <Root>
      <Counter />
    </Root>
  );
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapped.unmount(); // it cleans the mount after test.
});

describe(`This is counter component`, () => {
  it(`This is show intial Value`, () => {
    expect(wrapped.find(`h1`).text()).toEqual(`1`);
  });

  it(`after click it will increase the value`, () => {
    expect(wrapped.find(`h1`).text()).toEqual(`1`);
    wrapped.find(`button`).at(0).find(`[data-test="increment"]`).simulate(`click`);
    expect(wrapped.find(`h1`).text()).toEqual(`2`);
  });
  it(`after click it will decrease the value`, () => {
    expect(wrapped.find(`h1`).text()).toEqual(`1`); // test failed because it expect 2
    wrapped.find(`button`).at(1).find(`[data-test="decrement"]`).simulate(`click`);
    expect(wrapped.find(`h1`).text()).toEqual(`0`);
  });
});
```

**This is my counter component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from 'store/reducer/counter/index';
import { IRootState } from 'store/combineReducer';
import styled from 'styled-components';
const Button = styled.button`
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
`;

const Text = styled.h1`
color: blue;
`;

export default () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.counter);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div >
      <Text>{counter}</Text>
      <Button data-test="increment" onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}>
        Increment counter
      </Button>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <Button data-test="decrement" onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>
        Decrement counter
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I believe the beforeEach and afterEach are also scoped, try moving them into the describe block with the tests you want them to run before and after each of.

Comment: I removed the describe but I am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: @Drew if you want I can share this code in codesandbox

Comment: I was going to ask if that was possible, actually. Sometimes it's much easier debugging something when you can see it when running.

Comment: please sir let me know, if you get my git repo. I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: I have lots of test . Because I am practicing for my work. Hope you will track the counter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it` block has a scope in a sense that a function has a scope, additionally other things like spies can be affected by currently running test. There are no problems with scopes here, the only thing that is affected by scopes is `wrapper` variable and it's defined in a scope that is common to all tests. Since it's reassigned in `beforeEach`, it cannot result in test cross-contamination.

The problem here is that there's global state because Redux naturally provides one.

Most commonly a custom store is set up for tests so initial value, etc. could be manipulated depending on testing needs:

```
let wrapped;

beforeEach(() => {
  const store = ...

  wrapped = mount(
    <Provider store={store}><Counter /></Provider>
  );
});
```

This is what [the documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) recommends.

Alternatively, a store and all modules that directly depend on it needs to be re-imported per test, this should be done instead of top-level import of these modules:

```
let wrapped;
let Root;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
  Root = require("root/index");

  wrapped = mount(
    <Root>
      <Counter />
    </Root>
  );
});
```

Comment: I just got only issue with the counter component. but with other reducers it works fine.

Comment: This means that cross-contamination didn't affect other tests yet - or you didn't notice it. The answer already explains what's wrong. It's still relevant regarding your repo. Always provide a fresh store to connected components.

Comment: It did not affect on other tests. I followed the setup from one Udemy course I took it.

Comment: Test suites (.test.* files) run in separate processes so this only affects tests inside a suite. There's no magic in it, Redux provides global state and if you share it between tests, it works as global state because it's supposed to. Providing a custom store with `<Provider store={store}>` is how it's usually done in tests.

Comment: This is honestly why I prefer *not* using the redux hooks and using the `connect` HOC instead. This allows me to export the unconnected component for testing and I can simply just mock the props redux provides.